# Set timeout on third-party file request with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, http

I'm trying to integrate a script file hosted by a third party into a new web site.

Currently, I'm adding a SCRIPT tag to the DOM for that third-party script file on document ready:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    var extScript = document.createElement('script');
        extScript.type = 'text/javascript';
        extScript.src = 'http://third-party.com/scriptfile.js';

    $('head').append(extScript);

});

function extScriptCallback() {
    $('#extWidgetContainer').show();
}
```

But sometimes that third-party script file request times out or takes a long time to respond.

So, for the sake of best practice, I want to provide alternative content if the external script takes longer than e.g. 10 seconds to load.

How do I achieve this?  I've looked at JavaScript's native setTimeout(), as well as jQuery's delay() function, but I'm not sure which I should use--or how.

Grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can approach this.  The first method would be to check on a timer for the existence of a function or variable provided by the third party script.  If it's not available when you check for it, it's not loaded yet:

```
$(document).ready( function() {  
    var extScript = document.createElement('script');
        extScript.type = 'text/javascript';
        extScript.src = 'http://third-party.com/scriptfile.js';

    window.setTimeout(function ()
    {
        if ("thirdPartyFuncName" in window)
            alert("loaded");
        else
            alert("Not loaded yet");
    }, 10000); // 10 secs

    $('head').append(extScript);
});
```

The other way you could go is to investigate the `onload` and `onreadystatechange` events provided by browsers.  AFAIK, `onload` is widely implemented, so you could do something like this:

```
var timer;
extScript.onload = function () { clearTimeout(timer); }
timer = window.setTimeout(function ()
{
    alert("not loaded");
}, 10000); // 10 secs
```

The downside to this approach is that the load event will fire even if the script has a syntax error, so I still think the first approach is your best bet, because it checks for functionality existence.

Comment: why not use both methods? Also, you can use onerror to detect scripts if they fail to load.

Comment: @David Murdoch: I'm not 100% sure on the compatibility or reliability of the `onload` and `onerror` methods, or what conditions need to be met for them to fire -- e.g. does `onerror` only apply to network-related errors or do parsing errors fire it too?  You could use both methods but I think the first alone should suffice.

Comment: @David Murdoch: it also appears that IE doesn't support `onerror` for script elements, although the documentation says otherwise: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027849/how-to-trigger-script-onerror-in-internet-explorer/2032014#2032014

Comment: well, ie sucks. It can still be used for the other browsers, right?

Comment: @David: Sure, I think most, if not all, other popular browsers support `onerror`.  I can't say it's something I've played around with much, tbh.

Comment: Thanks, Andy. Your first method looks sound, so I'll be going with that one.  Huge help, much appreciated.