# javascript IP address question, what if fail to load/no internet connectivity

Tags: javascript, json

I have some code that if I'm at home; it will display at popup saying that if you are at home. If you are not at home it will display a popup saying you are not at home. As the script is located on a server to give an IP address, how can I get it to say if you are not connected to the internet, as it will fail to load so I would have though that ip!="" would work but doesn't what have I done wrong?
Thanks

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    function getip(json)
    {
        ip=json.ip
        if(ip!="")
        {
            if(ip=="123.123.123.123")
            {
                alert("You are at home");
            }
            else
            {
                alert("you are not at home");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            alert("You are not connected to the internet");
        }
    }
</script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="http://jsonip.appspot.com/?callback=getip">
</script>
```

Comment: If the JSONP fails to load, your whole function won't be called, will it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way JSONP works is to call that method with the response, your server response from `http://jsonip.appspot.com/?callback=getip` looks something like this:

```
getip({ "ip": "123.123.123.123", "addres": "123.123.123.123" });
```

But when you're not connected that script include just errors, and the method *isn't ever called*, that's the issue.  Your `if` check, and the entire `getip()` method, isn't ever hit.  You could do a very simple timeout, like this:

```
var timer = setTimeout(function() { 
  alert("You are not connected to the internet");
}, 10000); //10 seconds
function getip(json){
  clearTimeout(timer);
  if(json.ip == "123.123.123.123") {
    alert("You are at home");
  } else {
    alert("you are not at home");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that if the JSONP fails to load, the whole function won't be called at all.

In theory, there is the `onerror` event for the `<script>` element that you could use, but according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027849/how-to-trigger-script-onerror-in-internet-explorer), it doesn't work reliably in IE.

However, that question shows a workaround that might work for you, too: Embedding a script that sets a variable, and checking for that variable afterwards. That would be an option if you control the remote app that you are calling.

If that is not a possibility, I think the only thing you can do is have the callback function set a flag like `json_loaded = true;` and use a `setTimeout` to check for that flag after a few seconds. If the flag is not set, the script failed to load and you need to act accordingly.

Comment: If you prefer not to write the code for this, you could use jquery-jsonp http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/