# Load Script with jQuery - IE fails

Tags: jquery

i try to load a JavaScript dynamically with jQuery to initlialize my ajax-application. I want to get a handler-function called, when the script was loaded successfully. This is what my code looks like:

```
var $script = $('<script type="text/javascript"></script>').appendTo('head');
$script.load(function() { ... });
$script.error(function() { ... });
$script.attr('src', 'foo.js');
```

This works fine in FireFox, Opera, Safari and Chromium.
The onload-handler is always called after the script was loaded.
But the IE (v8) does neither call the onload-handler nor the onerror-handler. So my ajax-application gets never initialized ;-)

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Best Regards,
Biggie

EDIT:
I think i got it working:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: options.script,
    data: null,
    success: function(data, textStatus) {
        options.onload();
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        options.onerror();
    },
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        // Fix for FireFox 3 to prevent "malformed"-message
        if (xhr.overrideMimeType) {
            xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain");
        }
    },
    dataType: "script"
});
```

The `beforeSend` is used to prevent the `malformed`-error in FireFox.

This seems to work with FireFox and IE. Both call the error-handler if the script does not exist.

Comment: as others have noted the 'onload' event is not triggered in IE. You should handle the onreadystatechange for IE to have it working.

Comment: @andreas: This should be automatically done by the `ajax`-function if i understand the jQuery-code correct: http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L294

Answer (score 3):

jQuery has [getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

```
jQuery.getScript( url, [ success(data, textStatus) ] )
```

Comment: But getScript has no onError-Handler. So there is no way to inform the user hat the initialize has failed.

Comment: @Biggie "So there is no way to inform the user hat the initialize has failed." How about `textStatus`?

Comment: Hm, if the requested file does not exist the success-function is not called (FireFox). Moreover the FireFox-log always shows an error like "malformed code" although the code works without problems.

Answer (score 0):

@epascarello's answer is probably the most convenient way to go.

Other than that:

`onerror` doesn't work for script elements in IE. See detailed background in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027849/how-to-trigger-script-onerror-in-internet-explorer).

`onload` is supposed to work according to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197055(VS.85).aspx). If it really doesn't, a workaround might be to execute the function in the JS that gets embedded.

Answer (score 0):

`error` won't work reliably in either case, however [`$.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) (and [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) underneath) [uses `onreadystatechange` as well to support IE](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L307), so you can do this:

```
$.getScript("foo.js", function() { /* run your app code */ });
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost 1 year later...

I made a little change in jquery source code to support correctly 404 error when calling a script.

Search in source for "*jQuery.ajaxTransport( "script", function(s) {*" and in the body of the function (I added before onload event) add:

```
[...]
// Attach error event handler
script.onerror = function(){ callback(0, "error"); };
[...]
```

This modification will fire the "error" callback. So you can create a fallback function for 404 error.

This is a dirty modification, but worked perfectly in most browsers that I tested (FF,Chrome,Webkit,IE7-9)