# Detect 404 error from included JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, include, http-status-code-404, jsonp

I am making a cross-domain JSON(P) call by using JavaScript to add a `<script>` tag to the DOM with that URL I want included as the `src`. The script being loaded has a callback that calls a function on my page, and the data I want is returned as an argument to the function.

There are 2 catches, though:

1. Sometimes the JSONP page will return a 400 or 404 error.
2. The same JSONP file can be requested multiple times on the same page (each time returning different data)

So, I need to detect when the callback function is not fired (which would indicate that the JSONP file returned an error), but I also need to account for the fact that the same file can be requested twice. Essentially, I need to detect the error in loading the page, but I have to do it before the other files finish loading. And yes, the files should be loaded (or return an error) in the correct order.

**One (inefficient) solution:**

I could make a bunch of different functions that are requested for each different file load (eg. callbackFunction0, callbackFunction1, etc). That way, I can simply determine when one of the functions didn't fire and have my JavaScript act off of that. However, this would take up a lot of space an be inefficient because I would have to have one callbackFunction for the maximum time the script would be loaded on the same page (this number has no definite value, though, so if I only made 15 functions and the script was requested 20 times, errors would occur).

This was kind of difficult to explain, but hopefully you got the idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, I made the callback include a variable containing the request number. So the callback might be `var requestnumber=0;callbackFunction`. Then I could figure out which request applied to which element. I should have thought of this before.

Answer (score 2):

[$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) have many callback functions which you can utilize.

```
$.ajax({
      url: "test.html?callback=?",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      success: function(data){
        // your logic
      }
      statusCode: {
        404: function() {
          alert('page not found');
        }
      }
});
```

Comment: I am not using jQuery (unfortunately). Also, does that work cross-domain?

Answer (score 1):

You could just add a argument to the callbackfunction containing the id/number/position of the script. So something like callbackFunction(1, ...rest of arguments..). No need to create new function-names.

You could detect the error by attaching the onerror event to the script element.
Somewhat related: [How to trigger script.onerror in Internet Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027849/how-to-trigger-script-onerror-in-internet-explorer)