# self invoking function in for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, self-invoking-function

Here's code from  https://github.com/Khan/khan-exercises/blob/master/khan-exercise.js

```
for ( var i = 0; i < loading; i++ ) (function( mod ) {
    if ( !testMode && mod.src.indexOf("/khan-exercises/") === 0 && mod.src.indexOf("/MathJax/") === -1 ) {
        // Don't bother loading khan-exercises content in production
        // mode, this content is already packaged up and available
        // (*unless* it's MathJax, which is silly still needs to be loaded)
        loaded++;
        return;
    }

    // Adapted from jQuery getScript (ajax/script.js)
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.async = "async";

    for ( var prop in mod ) {
        script[ prop ] = mod[ prop ];
    }

    script.onerror = function() {
        // No error in IE, but this is mostly for debugging during development so it's probably okay
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027849/how-to-trigger-script-onerror-in-internet-explorer
        Khan.error( "Error loading script " + script.src );
    };

    script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if ( !script.readyState || ( /loaded|complete/ ).test( script.readyState ) ) {
            // Handle memory leak in IE
            script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;

            // Remove the script
            if ( script.parentNode ) {
                script.parentNode.removeChild( script );
            }

            // Dereference the script
            script = undefined;

            runCallback();
        }
    };

    head.appendChild(script);
})( urls[i] );
```

Strange thing: instead of usual for loop code block we see self invoking function!(inside of other self invoking function) Why is that? how will this function run?

Comment: That is a regular for loop. It is effectively just one statement with no { }s.

Comment: There's only one "self-invoking function", the one executed for each element in the `urls` array. The only other functions are event-handling callbacks.

Comment: Self-invoking function? Nonsense. You mean immediately invoked function `:P`

Comment: @DaveNewton i meant other self-invoking function is the function that wraps around all code in whole js file.

Comment: @DrStrangeLove We can only answer what we see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the `for loop` runs the function each time with value `url[i]` passed into the `mod` parameter.

```
for ( var i = 0; i < loading; i++ ) (function( mod ) {...The code...})(urls[i]);
```

if you notice in the code you will see this

```
(function( mod ) {...The code...})(urls[i])
```

which is a function call passing `urls[i]`  in to the parameter `mod`

Comment: What seen pointless since I don't see that value used in any of the inner closures.

Comment: @Prusse ... `mod` is used all over the place?  I do not understand your comment?

Comment: Also, a local variable `script` is created. The immediately invoked function expression acts as a namespace here - its usage is for convenience.

Comment: Didn't see that, bad of me, sorry.

Comment: Does for loop run the function?? or Does the function self invoke?? it should self invoke, right??

Comment: The for loop runs the function `0 to value in loading` times.  passing `i` into `urls[i]` on each iteration.  So (in a way) yes the for loop runs the function. Yes the function does self invoke.

Answer (score 1):

It's an odd construct, but basically if you exclude the `{}` from a for loop, it will simply run the next line for each iteration, it's similar to excluding `{}` with an `if` if you want a one-line `if`.

So it's basically equivalent to this:

```
function doSomething(){...}

for ( var i = 0; i < loading; i++ ) {
   doSomething(urls[i]);
}
```

Where doSomething is that large function.