# Javascript detect static <script> load failues

Tags: javascript, html

This is similar to [How to tell if a <script> tag failed to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538745/how-to-tell-if-a-script-tag-failed-to-load). But my question is specifically about plain old `<script>` tags in my HTML body like so

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/my/script.js"></script>
```

I have a custom `window.onerror` function that I wrote to deal with general script errors. And indeed, if such a script has a syntax error or some other runtime error occurs while evaluating the script itself, that is handled correctly by my `onerror` function.

But if the script fails to load at all, because of an interrupted connection or even a 404 or other server error, `window.onerror` is not called. How can I detect this kind of failure programmatically in Javascript?

To clarify: I realize I could just put an `onerror` attribute in every single script tag. I'm asking if there's a better way, something comparable to my global `window.onerror` or some way of making that function be called.

Comment: I think this is exact duplicate of a post you linked. No matter how many times I read this. Is it just me?

Comment: That's why I mentioned "static" in my question and actually wrote out the script tag - this is _not_ a dynamic script, it's just a plain old `script` tag in my HTML.

Comment: But I guess I see your point - it sounds like I need to add an `onerror` attribute to my script tag. Is that really the only way?

Comment: Where – in your opinion – is the difference between a `script` tag that was already inserted in the template and a `script` tag that was inserted later using JS? I don't see what is so special about your question in contrast to the one you've linked to.

Comment: Well, for example, for dynamic scripts I can use Ajax (in my case, wrapped with jQuery) and I will have an XHR object with a readyState and status that I can examine.

Comment: @Dan I think there are many solutions, for example I think you could do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/VN7Na/ but modify it to contain less hard coding, you could even calculate expected number of src="" includes in that page and verify how many failed etc.? Also I think another one is to validate against js variable which should come from a script: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027849/how-to-trigger-script-onerror-in-internet-explorer/2032014#2032014 also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293367/how-to-detect-if-javascript-files-are-loaded

Answer (score 0):

You can check youruniquefunction in your script tag

```
 if (typeof youruniquefunction!== 'undefined' ) {
   // your script ok
}
```