# Detect network errors in <script> tags

Tags: javascript, html

This is the question I was attempting to ask in [Javascript detect static <script> load failues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936307/javascript-detect-static-script-load-failues) but I think I may have confused the issue.

My question is: suppose I have a `<script>` tag in some HTML and it doesn't load, not because of any error in the code but because of a network error. Is there any way to be programmatically notified of this network error? I see that I can attach an `onerror` event to the script tag, but the callback for that gets nothing but an `Event` object passed to it and no information about the network failure.

By contrast, if I'm loading the script dynamically through Ajax, I have an XHR object that has some information I can use in it. I'm looking for something comparable with static `<script>` tags.

Basically what I want is something like this

```
<script src="/path/to/script.js" type="text/javascript" onerror="handleError(event)"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
       function handleError(event) {
            // do stuff;
       }
</script>
```

where "stuff" would include details of the network error that prevented the script from loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please post code to help us help you.

Well either the page loaded or it didn't, network errors cannot cause script errors unless an external file failed to load or an ajax command returned a non 200 status. If the problem is from ajax you can test the ajax object for the response code when its ready and if it is other than 200 you can run your notification or retry code, if the error is from an external .js file not loading for whatever reason add a variable to the js file such as var loaded = true; then check against it in your main file and react as needed.

Comment: I understand I can do that. I'm saying I want to know explicitly what made it not load - was it a gateway timeout, an aborted request, or something else.

Comment: There is no way to test for 400/500 errors on embedded resources I don't believe, ajax does however respond with a standard response type, so ajax can provide the relative information, but no embeded .js files.

Comment: thanks. I was afraid that might be the case but couldn't confirm it.